# Service Fabric FABRIC_E_IMAGEBUILDER_VALIDATION_ERROR: DOWNLOAD PATH SANITIZED Error

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-deployment

I am deploying a Service Fabric application and encountered this error for a resource of type `Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/applicationTypes/versions`:

```
Status: Failed
Error:
Code: ClusterChildResourceOperationFailed
Message: Resource operation failed. Operation: CreateOrUpdate. Error details: {
"Details": "FABRIC_E_IMAGEBUILDER_VALIDATION_ERROR: DOWNLOAD PATH SANITIZED"
}
```

Has anyone run into this issue before? If so, what was the root cause of the error?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: I used Powershell to try deploying to my local cluster (see [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/register-servicefabricapplicationtype?view=azureservicefabricps#example-5--register-an-application-type-from-an-external-store-async) and the error shows more detail now -> FABRIC_E_IMAGEBUILDER_VALIDATION_ERROR: The package downloaded from '<blobUrl>' has application type name '<type in manifest>', which doesn't match expected value '<type declared during creation>'.

Answer (score 3):

When I encountered this error, my application type name in my manifest did not match the application type name that I was deploying to.

It is possible to view far more useful/relevant error messages under these scenarios by going to the Service Fabric Explorer.

e.g.
`https://{my-service-fabric-clustername.example.com}:19080/Explorer/old.html#`

NOTE: The "new" UI does not show these useful error details, you need to select the "View old SFX" interface option

[image: View old SFX interface]

Then clicking on the "Type" that I was uploading the application to, revelaed far more descriptive and helpful errors:
[image: Type Essentials panel displays more useful error messages]

Comment: It is supported now. Just click on the application type on the left side and then on the right side in tab 'Essentials' and under 'Application Type versions' click on 'All'. It will show the error.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, this is an issue with the version number of the sfpkg not aligning with the version in the template's `Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/applicationTypes/versions`. Try looking into the application package's **ApplicationManifest.xml** file for ApplicationTypeVersion for the right version.